# SIGABRT when deleting object moved to container

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an interface:

```
struct Interface{
  Interface(const Interface &) = delete;
  auto operator = (const Interface &) -> Interface & = delete;
  virtual ~Interface() = 0;
};
```

I have an implementation:

```
struct Impl : public Interface {
  Impl(const Impl &) = delete;
  auto operator = (const Impl &) -> Impl & = delete;
  bool m_is_borrowed{false};
  std::weak_ptr<Pool> m_pool;

  ~Impl() {
    if (m_is_borrowed) {
      if (auto pool = m_pool.lock()) {
        m_is_borrowed = false;
        auto conn = std::unique_ptr<Interface>(this);
        pool->m_objects.push_back(std::move(conn));
      }
    }
  }
};
```

As the code indicates `Pool` has a member of type `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Interface>>`

It also creates instances of Interface:

```
auto impl = std::unique_ptr<Interface>(new Implementation());
m_objects.push_back(std::move(impl));
```

And gives one to the user of `Pool`:

```
auto get() -> std::unique_ptr<Interface> {
  return std::move(m_objects.front());
}
```

So what I'm trying to do is, when an instance of `Implementation` is deleted, check if it's been borrowed from `Pool` and if that's the case, send it back to the pool. If it's *in* the pool, let it be deleted normally.

Sending the instance back to the pool works, but when I try to delete objects when `Pool` is deleted I get the following error:

```
integration(46154,0x1003855c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x101900000: pointer being freed was not allocated
integration(46154,0x1003855c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

with the following stack trace:

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff6418d23e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff64243c1c libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 285
    frame #2: 0x00007fff640f61c9 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 127
    frame #3: 0x00007fff642056e2 libsystem_malloc.dylib`malloc_vreport + 545
    frame #4: 0x00007fff642054a3 libsystem_malloc.dylib`malloc_report + 152
    frame #5: 0x000000010000fa82 integration`Implementation::~Implementation(this=0x0000000101900000) at Implementation.cpp:14
    frame #6: 0x000000010000a449 integration`std::__1::__vector_base<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> > > >::~__vector_base() [inlined] std::__1::default_delete<Interface>::operator(this=0x0000000101800c58, __ptr=0x0000000101900000)(Interface*) const at memory:2285
    frame #7: 0x000000010000a421 integration`std::__1::__vector_base<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> > > >::~__vector_base() [inlined] std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> >::reset(this=0x0000000101800c58, __p=0x0000000000000000) at memory:2598
    frame #8: 0x000000010000a3b0 integration`std::__1::__vector_base<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> > > >::~__vector_base() [inlined] std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> >::~unique_ptr(this=0x0000000101800c58) at memory:2552
    frame #9: 0x000000010000a3b0 integration`std::__1::__vector_base<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> > > >::~__vector_base() [inlined] std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> >::~unique_ptr(this=0x0000000101800c58) at memory:2552
    frame #10: 0x000000010000a3b0 integration`std::__1::__vector_base<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> > > >::~__vector_base() [inlined] std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> > >::destroy(this=0x0000000101800a58, __p=0x0000000101800c58) at memory:1860
    frame #11: 0x000000010000a358 integration`std::__1::__vector_base<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> > > >::~__vector_base() [inlined] void std::__1::allocator_traits<std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> > > >::__destroy<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> > >(__a=0x0000000101800a58, __p=0x0000000101800c58) at memory:1727
    frame #12: 0x000000010000a33c integration`std::__1::__vector_base<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> > > >::~__vector_base() [inlined] void std::__1::allocator_traits<std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> > > >::destroy<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> > >(__a=0x0000000101800a58, __p=0x0000000101800c58) at memory:1595
    frame #13: 0x000000010000a320 integration`std::__1::__vector_base<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> > > >::~__vector_base() [inlined] std::__1::__vector_base<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> > > >::__destruct_at_end(this=0x0000000101800a48, __new_last=0x0000000101800c50) at vector:413
    frame #14: 0x000000010000a297 integration`std::__1::__vector_base<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> > > >::~__vector_base() [inlined] std::__1::__vector_base<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> > > >::clear(this=0x0000000101800a48) at vector:356
    frame #15: 0x000000010000a27f integration`std::__1::__vector_base<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> > > >::~__vector_base(this=0x0000000101800a48) at vector:441
    frame #16: 0x000000010000a235 integration`std::__1::vector<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> > > >::~vector(this=0x0000000101800a48 size=2) at iterator:1425
    frame #17: 0x0000000100002395 integration`std::__1::vector<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<Interface, std::__1::default_delete<Interface> > > >::~vector(this=0x0000000101800a48 size=2) at iterator:1425
    frame #18: 0x0000000100002478 integration`Pool::~Pool(this=0x00000001018009d8) at Pool.cpp:17
    frame #19: 0x0000000100002565 integration`Pool::~Pool(this=0x00000001018009d8) at Pool.cpp:15
    frame #20: 0x0000000100167029 integration`std::__1::__shared_ptr_emplace<Pool, std::__1::allocator<Pool> >::__on_zero_shared(this=0x00000001018009c0) at memory:3656
    frame #21: 0x000000010000cc01 integration`std::__1::shared_ptr<Pool>::~shared_ptr() [inlined] std::__1::__shared_count::__release_shared(this=0x00000001018009c0) at memory:3490
    frame #22: 0x000000010000cbb7 integration`std::__1::shared_ptr<Pool>::~shared_ptr() [inlined] std::__1::__shared_weak_count::__release_shared(this=0x00000001018009c0) at memory:3532
    frame #23: 0x000000010000cbb7 integration`std::__1::shared_ptr<Pool>::~shared_ptr(this=0x00007ffeefbfe1a0) at memory:4468
    frame #24: 0x0000000100002da5 integration`std::__1::shared_ptr<Pool>::~shared_ptr(this=0x00007ffeefbfe1a0) at memory:4466
    frame #25: 0x0000000100165d1f integration`____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____0() at Pool.cpp:30
    frame #26: 0x00000001000516e3 integration`Catch::TestInvokerAsFunction::invoke(this=0x0000000100702b90) const at catch.hpp:11605
    frame #27: 0x000000010003e277 integration`Catch::TestCase::invoke(this=0x0000000101800760) const at catch.hpp:11506
    frame #28: 0x000000010003e16d integration`Catch::RunContext::invokeActiveTestCase(this=0x00007ffeefbff308) at catch.hpp:10365
    frame #29: 0x0000000100039abb integration`Catch::RunContext::runCurrentTest(this=0x00007ffeefbff308, redirectedCout="", redirectedCerr="") at catch.hpp:10339
    frame #30: 0x0000000100037387 integration`Catch::RunContext::runTest(this=0x00007ffeefbff308, testCase=0x0000000101800760) at catch.hpp:10115
    frame #31: 0x0000000100042c39 integration`Catch::(anonymous namespace)::runTests(config=std::__1::shared_ptr<Catch::Config>::element_type @ 0x0000000101800228 strong=4 weak=1) at catch.hpp:10667
    frame #32: 0x00000001000417e6 integration`Catch::Session::runInternal(this=0x00007ffeefbff780) at catch.hpp:10862
    frame #33: 0x00000001000414c5 integration`Catch::Session::run(this=0x00007ffeefbff780) at catch.hpp:10819
    frame #34: 0x000000010007ef8a integration`int Catch::Session::run<char>(this=0x00007ffeefbff780, argc=2, argv=0x00007ffeefbff8f8) at catch.hpp:10565
    frame #35: 0x000000010007eed2 integration`main(argc=2, argv=0x00007ffeefbff8f8) at catch.hpp:14318
    frame #36: 0x00007fff6404ded9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #37: 0x00007fff6404ded9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Step by step debugging shows that when `Pool` is destroyed `m_is_borrowed` is false so no new unique_ptr instances are created. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: `auto conn = std::unique_ptr<Interface>(this);` are you sure? You are sending raw pointer to the pool, but you do it in **destructor** of `Impl`, so when dtor ends this is invalid pointer, and when the pool is deleted it calls `delete invalidatedPointer` as default action of unique_ptr dtor.

Comment: But I'm moving it into the connection?

Comment: After it's been moved, it'll be `free`d.

Comment: After the move it should still exist in the vector of impls no? After all its been moved into a container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
auto get() -> std::unique_ptr<Interface> {
    return std::move(m_objects.front());
}
```

You haven't actually `erase`d the pointer from the pool above. Check the `size()` of `m_objects` before and after a call to `get()` and you'll find that the size is exacly the same before and after. You're leaving an empty `unique_ptr` at `front()`.

Consider something like:

```
auto get() -> std::unique_ptr<Interface> {
    auto rv = std::move(m_objects.front());
    m_objects.erase(m_objects.begin());
    return rv;
}
```

Or more efficiently, let it pick one from the `back()` since the vector then won't have to move its data:

```
auto get() -> std::unique_ptr<Interface> {
    auto rv = std::move(m_objects.back());
    m_objects.pop_back();
    return rv;
}
```

Problem two:

```
~Impl() {
    if (m_is_borrowed) {
        if (auto pool = m_pool.lock()) {
            m_is_borrowed = false;
            auto conn = std::unique_ptr<Interface>(this);
            pool->m_objects.push_back(std::move(conn));
        }
    }
}
```

Here you create a `unique_ptr` and give it ownership of `this`. When `~Impl()` returns, the memory pointed to by `this` will (normally) be `free`d. The `unique_ptr` now owns an invalid pointer and when doing `delete` on that pointer, anything can happen.

Here's an example to illustrate it. I've replaced `unique_ptr` with `smart` that has some logging. Each instance of `smart` also has an `id` that can be tracked.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
struct smart {
    static int instance;
    int id;
    T* ptr;

    smart() : id(++instance), ptr(nullptr) {}
    smart(T* p) : id(++instance), ptr(p) {
        std::cout << "smart("<<id<<") ctor got ptr: " << std::boolalpha << (ptr!=nullptr) << "\n";
    }
    smart(const smart&) = delete;
    smart(smart&& o) : id(++instance), ptr(std::exchange(o.ptr, nullptr)) {
        std::cout << "smart("<<id<<") move ctor from "<<o.id<<"\n";
    }
    smart& operator=(const smart&) = delete;
    smart& operator=(smart&& o) {
        delete ptr;
        ptr = std::exchange(o.ptr, nullptr);
        std::cout << "smart("<<id<<") move assign from "<<o.id<<"\n";
    }
    ~smart() {
        std::cout << "~smart("<<id<<") real delete: " << std::boolalpha << (ptr!=nullptr) << "\n";
        delete ptr;
    }
};
template<typename T>
int smart<T>::instance = 0;

struct try_me;

std::vector<smart<try_me>> pool;

struct try_me {
    try_me() { std::cout << "try_me\n"; }
    ~try_me() {
        std::cout << "~try_me -- start --\n";
        auto tmp = smart<try_me>(this);
        pool.push_back(std::move(tmp));
        std::cout << "~try_me -- end --\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    pool.emplace_back(new try_me);
    std::cout << "--------------\n";
    pool.pop_back();
    std::cout << "--------------\n";
}
```

Possible output:

```
try_me
smart(1) ctor got ptr: true
--------------
~smart(1) real delete: true
~try_me -- start --
smart(2) ctor got ptr: true
smart(3) move ctor from 2
~try_me -- end --
~smart(2) real delete: false
--------------
~smart(3) real delete: true
~try_me -- start --
smart(4) ctor got ptr: true
smart(5) move ctor from 4
smart(6) move ctor from 3
~smart(3) real delete: false
~try_me -- end --
~smart(4) real delete: false
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: I am aware of that. How does it related to my error?

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't but it looks suspicious enough and I didn't spot the error @rafix07 spotted. Btw, since you are aware of what your current `get()` does, what's the purpose of it?

Comment: It's designed to return an Interface to the user?

Comment: ... so why return an empty `unique_ptr` to the user?

Comment: It's not empty? I'm very confused about this.

Comment: `return std::move(m_objects.front());` leaves an empty `unique_ptr` at `front()`. and the suggestion I made in my answer does not.

Comment: I see what you mean. That's handled in the real code.

Comment: Can you put the real code for `get()` in the question?